# how to upload a big file yii2

Tags: php, file, yii2

I am trying to upload files. When I upload file less than 2mb it's OK. But when I'm trying bigger than 2mb I get fatal error:

```
Call to a member function saveAs() on null
```

By the way, validation in form is successfull: rules works good.

There is my model class:

```
class UploadForm extends Model
{
    /**
     * @var UploadedFile
     */
    public $xmlFile;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['xmlFile'], 'file', 'maxSize' => 20480000, 'tooBig' => "Limit is 20mb"],
        ];
    }

    public function upload()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            $this->xmlFile->saveAs('uploads/xml/' . $this->xmlFile->baseName . '.' . $this->xmlFile->extension);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my form:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'xmlFile')->fileInput() ?>


    <button>Submit</button>

<?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

My action:

```
 if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
            $model->xmlFile = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'xmlFile');
            if ($model->upload()) {
                //$import->import($model);

                return $this->render('upload', ['model' => $model, 'message' => "Success"]);

            }
        }
```

Comment: Plz, check your server settings. Often limits in your `php.ini` file is setted to 2mb by default. Check values of parameter `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`

Comment: @s_mart Yeeaah! Now it works!

Comment: Great, than i'll add this as answer :) Good luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the problem is in limits in your `php.ini` file. By default they are setted to 2mb. Check values of parameter `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`